# Create a new image or share source code in a volume in a docker container in development?

Tags: java, python, docker, docker-image

I'm wondering what would be the best practice to update the source code in a docker container that is run within( in JAVA and python). I could either modify my code, create a new image and run a container. In Java,  I would also need to compile the code. 
Another solution would be to just use a volume to share the code between my machine and the container so that each time I modify the behavior of my code I won't need to create a new docker image.

I'm asking all of this for development purposes, not deploying
Is there a best practice between these two solutions? What are the pros and cons? Is there a difference for a compiled language like a java compared to python?

Comment: For development? You can bind a local volume, and this is a common pattern.

Comment: does this work for Java/maven too?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what's in the container, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely make a new image instead of sharing the code via a mounted volume. Then whole docker ideology is to produce a self-contained "service", which can be portable across server (i.e. copy the image). Yuo docker file and image build process will track versions of your code, i.e. in your docker file you can pull a specific branch, or you can tag the image with a specific tag.
In case of a mounted volume, you never sure what version of your code is actually. run.

Hope this reason alone will help you to decide.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm asking for development, I just fixed my question. Does your answer still apply?

Comment: yes, since you are developing, you'll then be able to pass your tagged image to testing, and they eventaully promote to production

Answer (score 2):

this was my question and I found it in this way For development, you can bind a volume.
in this example, I assume you have exposed a port on 3000 also instead of an absolute project address **NOTE** if you are in the project directory within your shell you can use $(pwd)

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -v absolute-project-address:/app image-name
```

also you can add your volume name for storing data

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -v absolute-project-address:/app -v volumeName:/app/data image-name
```

But for the production, you must create an image

Answer (score 1):

In general the best practice would be to create a new image when you have new source code and run a new container from that image. Docker can quickly create and run new images, so you should take advantage of that. In addition you can know what version of your code you're running by tagging your images.

You mention that you would need to compile the Java code in the Docker case, but you would need to in either case. You could just compile your code into a Jar and then ADD (or COPY) the Jar into your container and run it there.

A couple of quick downsides that come to mind with the external code approach: you would need some external way to manage what version of code is running, docker tags take care of that for you. You would also need some way to alert the Docker container that a new executable file is ready and then have Docker run that. In addition you would need to make sure that your Docker container is running the same version of Java (or Python) that your system is running, this too is taken care of in Docker since you can build from a Java base image.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a new image, and if you think creating a new image and deploying is a task for you, than you can setup a CI/CD pipeline which will automatically compile java code, create a image and will deploy it for you whenever you push a code to GIT.